# Do soft closing interior door hinges exist?

Tags: doors, hinges

I just bought a bunch of soft closing hinges for my kitchen cabinets and this led me to thinking if there is any such hinges for regular interior doors like hallway/bathroom doors. It would be great if you can prevent slamming of doors and have it so if closed far enough the door will pull shut but softly.

I've been looking and haven't been able to find anything but self closing hinges, which do not have a soft close feature. Looking for someone that might know! TIA!

Comment: Look at the door closers on your screen door and on commercial doors. Something designed for the weight of your interior doors should do the trick.

Comment: This question is not asking for a product recommendation but a product existence query. Voting to re-open.

Comment: @Triplefault Yes you are correct, I am not asking for product recommendations, but information about whether a product exists!

Answer (score 3):

A bit of Googling shows me there aren't many, but there was one:

[Home Depot Everbilt 4" soft-close door hinge](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Everbilt-4-in-Square-Radius-Satin-Nickel-Soft-Close-Hinge-29186/314151000?MERCH=REC-_-pipinstock-_-314151892-_-%7B%7BproductId%7D%7D-_-N)

[image: Home Depot soft-close hinge]

There are also soft-close plungers or dampers, like this one:

[Amazon soft-close dampers](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00J9XB6BQ)

[image: Soft-close damper]

(No affiliation or recommendation, only web-search results)

Comment: Please don't do shopping for querents. Shopping questions are explicitly off-topic for a reason. Your links could be out of date within a week...

Comment: @FreeMan I respectfully but firmly disagree. The OP may not know what to call them or what to look for on the web. Showing them such things exist and what they're called is how to answer their question. This has been done before without complaint by other high-rep answerers. Even if the links die, the product names will still be usable. And the links are necessary for attribution, which would also be pinged against the answer if attribution were not given.

Comment: I agree with @Triplefault I didn't even know if these products exist. I wasn't asking for specific shopping recommendations I was asking for whether or not the product was even thought of or made to market yet by anyone. Also, I wasn't sure if the reason I wasn't finding anything in my research was because I didn't know the term for it which supports Triplefault's point.